# AWS S3 Static hosting - How to debug connection timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am following the [Setting up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) tutorial to the letter but something doesn't work and I don't know how to debug it.

Custom domain bought on Namecheap: **sankey.app**

**1/** The DNS of **sankey.app** is correctly directing to AWS - I can see in debug tools the **SOA** points to ns-63.awsdns-07.com.

**2/** The bucket is correctly configured, the index.html is statically hosted: http://sankey.app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

**3/** The Alias is created (with another one for www.sankey.app, but that should not be relevant).
[image]

But http://sankey.app/ returns Connection Timeout and even the protocol changes to **https**.

Now, I have experimented with **https** and **CloudFront** before but it didn't work so I disabled and deleted the distribution. There no active CloudFront distribution associated with the domain or bucket.

How can I debug this situation? I am a newbie and I am really helpless.

Comment: According to mxtoolbox, the A records for both resolve to AWS, so it's probably not DNS. I can access the S3 bucket directly, but not via your domain. Puzzling!

Comment: Odd. `curl sankey.app` returns a response, nearly instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your site is not configured to serve content over HTTPs but because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108241/non-authoritative-reason-header-field-http) Chrome trickery your are being silently forced to HTTPs.

Your domain is on the list of HSTS preloaded sites.

https://hstspreload.org/?domain=sankey.app

This is the reason why it works from curl and not in Chrome

In Chrome, right click -> Inspect -> Network Tab and then load http://sankey.app
you will see 307 redirect.

[image]

You will need to configure CloudFront distribution to terminate SSL for your S3 bucket or request removal from HSTS which takes ages (see hstspreload.org page)

Comment: Very nice catch.

Comment: How do I configure CloudFront distribution to terminate SSL for your S3 bucket? Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: This should help : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/ or this https://medium.com/@brodartec/hosting-a-static-site-with-https-enabled-using-aws-s3-cloudfront-and-godaddy-826dae41fdc6  its a common setup

Comment: It worked, except I could not add the CNAME record next to the A record. In the end, I realized I need to change the A from the bucket to the CloudFront distribution. Heureka!

Comment: Nice one, good work.